# What would be the best way add/implement continuous voice recognition in my Android app?

Tags: android, bluetooth, voice-recognition

Currently I have an application that functions as a Bluetooth server to a client application on my computer. I press a button on the app and it sends a corresponding key (F1 - F12) to the  computer and plays a song.

What I want to accomplish now is adding voice commands to the app so that the button functions could be conducted through voice, perhaps initiated through a hotword or button. For example, saying "One" would press button 1 or send the same command, same with a kill command of "stop".

Presently the primary driving thread of the app function is the OnTouch method which implements a series of case statements corresponding with the buttons.

```
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

     //*** Load animations 
     Animation spinin = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.custom_anim);

     Animation linear = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.in_out);     


    if(connected) {
        switch(event.getAction()) { 
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            switch(view.getId()) {



            case R.id.Image_SlideShow:               

                ring();

                mBluetoothService.write('1'); 
                Image1.startAnimation(spinin);
                processBackgroundSlide();

                break;  

            case R.id.Image1:     

                mBluetoothService.write('1'); 
                Image1.startAnimation(spinin);                  
                ring();
                processBackgroundSlide();
                break;

            case R.id.Image2:

                mBluetoothService.write('2'); 
                Image2.startAnimation(spinin);
                ring();
                Image_SlideShow.setImageResource(R.drawable.deep_blue_island_malvives_1920x896);                
                break;

            case R.id.Image3:

                mBluetoothService.write('3'); 
                Image3.startAnimation(spinin);
                ring();

                break;
            case R.id.Image4:                 
                mBluetoothService.write('4'); 
                Image4.startAnimation(spinin);
                ring();

                break;  
            case R.id.Image5:
                mBluetoothService.write('5'); 
                Image5.startAnimation(spinin);
                ring();
                break;

            case R.id.Image6:
                mBluetoothService.write('6'); 
                Image6.startAnimation(spinin);
                ring();
                break;                  

            case R.id.Image7:
                mBluetoothService.write('7'); 
                Image7.startAnimation(spinin);
                ring();

                break;                  


            case R.id.Image8:                 
                mBluetoothService.write('8'); 
                Image8.startAnimation(spinin);
                ring();
                break;

            case R.id.Image9: 

                mBluetoothService.write('9'); 
                Image9.startAnimation(spinin);

                ring();
                break;                  

            case R.id.Image10:                 
                mBluetoothService.write('A'); 
                Image10.startAnimation(spinin);
                ring();
                break;  


            case R.id.Image11:                 
                mBluetoothService.write('B'); 
                Image11.startAnimation(spinin);
                ring();
                break;                  

            case R.id.Image12:                 
                mBluetoothService.write('C'); 
                Image12.startAnimation(spinin);
                ring();
                break;  

            }  // end switch(view.getId())
            break;
        } // end switch(event.getAction())
    } // end if(connected)
    return true;
} // end onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event)
```

As you can see each button corresponds with a number and then sends it through the Bluetooth service, I keep thinking it should be an easy implementation to add a similar command through voice.

I've tried referencing some of the demos and threads on using speech-to-text but I've only had resulting crashes. I also was referencing [this thread involving switch statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731300/how-can-i-launch-my-android-activities-with-the-speech-recognizer) but that resulted in an multiple voice window prompts when pressing any button once.

Any direction or advice would be helpful, thank you in advance.

I'll also leave the OnActivityResult here too just in case it may help.

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch(requestCode) {
    case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE:
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // Get Device MAC Address
            String address = data.getExtras().getString(DeviceListActivity.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);
            // Get BluetoothDevice Object
            BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
            // Attempt to Connect to Device
            mBluetoothService.connect(device);              
            connected = true;
        }
        break;
    case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
        if(resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Log.d(TAG, "BT not enabled");
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.bt_not_enabled_leaving, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
        break;
    }   // end switch(requestCode)
}  // end protected void onActivityResult
```

**Specifically I'm more lost on how to exactly implement the voice recognition and commands as an activity. I see lots of examples on using it as a service, but being new to Android programming I don't have any direction.**